# How to increase Openfire concurrent connection limit?

Tags: java, xmpp, server, openfire, jabberd2

I am trying to test how many concurrent user connections **Openfire** can handle. I have noticed a limit at **4000** users. How can I handle **50000** concurrent connections or **more** on Openfire? What configuration should be done to handle large number of connections.

**My Server Config**

```
OS - Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 64 bit
Processor - 3.00 GHz
RAM - 512 MB
Openfire Version - 3.9.3
```

For testing purpose, I am using a virtual server setup on virtualbox.

**Scenario**

I'm testing Openfire 3.9.3 without connection manager and with no SSL either (yet). The server is a virtual machine setup on Virtualbox having 3.00GHz processor and 512MB RAM. It is a standard Openfire install with MySQL database connection with 100 maximum connections.

When testing with a load testing script from https://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-1232 [Please note I have not setup a cluster] the number of user connection increase steadily till 4000 concurrent user connections. Once 4000 users are connected, all connections begin to drop until all connections are lost and I get an error as follows:

```
java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:460)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:431)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
at OpenfireClusterStressTest.testMultipleLogin(OpenfireClusterStressTest.java:111)
at OpenfireClusterStressTest.main(OpenfireClusterStressTest.java:46)
```

**Issue**

Cannot handle more than 4000 concurrent user connections. How to increase this limit?
What openfire configuration is required to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to @Flow's answer...

If you are trying to connect from another computer, then you would have to increase the ulimit of that computer too.

**The mistake**

I had raised the limit of maximum number of open files.
But, I was trying to connect from another computer and the ulimit for the same was set to default.
Hence, the test would fail on reaching 4000 connections.

**Solution that worked for me**

When I updated the ulimit of the computer that runs the test script, it worked fine.
I am now able to achieve 20000 concurrent connections.

Answer (score 7):

You are not hitting an limit imposed by Openfire. Unix-like systems limit the maximum number of open file handles, and this includes (TCP) sockets, a process can have. You need to set a higher limit (it appears to be currently set to  something around 4000). The limit is usually modified with the `ulimit` command.

See also:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85457/how-to-circumvent-too-many-open-files-in-debian
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169004/number-of-open-files-configuration-not-operational

Comment: I had tried the same but it did not help. I still get the same error. The ulimit is set to 20000.

Comment: How did you verify the ulimit setting?

Comment: ulimit -Hn & ulimit -Sn

Comment: You are aware that this does report the ulimit of the current user?

Comment: Yes. I have set the same for root as well as *